# Saving String arrays to sharedPreference

Tags: java, android

I have gone through a lot of articles on the web that tries to analyse how array data could be save for future reuse but it seems as if they can't give me exactly what i want. 
I'm creating an android app which contains 30 buttons in one layout. 
Each button has it own String array  variable with 4 elements in each array.

```
String []mon_course1 ={"","","",""};
String []mon_course2 ={"","","",""};
// up to 30
```

all elements in the array contains different string data which is gotten from different EditText

```
mon_course1[0] = (editText1.getText().toString());
mon_course1[1] = (editText2.getText().toString());
mon_course1[2] = (editText3.getText().toString());
mon_course1[3] = (editText4.getText().toString());
```

Deciding which array String the EditText's data should be save to is handled by a **switch** statement. 
I'm able to set the arrays data from the corresponding EditText field
and also get the arrays data and set to TextViews

```
textView1.setText(mon_course1[0]);
textView2.setText(mon_course1[1]);
// till textView4
```

Now i want the data for each String array's element to be save in such that  it can be independently set to it corresponding textView
using **sharedPreference** or any other storage option. 
Please anyone that wants to help should clearly express his/her code and also use comment for better understanding because I'm just starting android programming. **THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
for(String str : arr) {
     edit.putString(str, str);
}
edit.apply();
```

Comment: Then how do i retrieve and set those data "1" "2" "3" to different textViews?

Comment: Indeed: retrieving is impossible.

Comment: @NellyRobert you need to set/know the "key" for example you can create, even, in xml array with keys(textview1, textview2, etc...)

Comment: What i mean is your array's first element is "1". now how can i call that "1" so that i can apply it to any view element let's use textView1 as the element.

Comment: String[] keys = new String[]{"textview1, "text2"};
Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
for(int i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
     edit.putString(keys[i], values[i]);
}
edit.apply();

String str = mPrefs.getString(keys[0], null);